# MS Access 2010 Query Equivalent

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Its my second day with MS Access, i am trying to update an existing application.
And this includes updating some queries. I never knew it was going to be so complex. the parenthesis issue in Access is really disturbing and i hit the wall, i get the "syntax error" error. My SQL query is something like this :

```
Select ….(Something)
Into …. (Some Table)
From A
Inner join B on A.ID=B.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN STAR as C on C.ID = A.ID
    AND C.Data = ’DEMO1’
    AND C.POS= ’POS1’
LEFT OUTER JOIN STAR as D on D.ID = A.ID
    AND D.Data = ’DEMO2’
    AND D.POS= ‘POS2’
LEFT OUTER JOIN STAR as E on E.ID = A.ID
    AND E.Data = ’DEMO3’
    AND E.POS= ‘POS3’
```

And in access, its equivalent that i am trying is :

```
Select ….
Into ….
From (((A
Inner join B on A.ID=B.ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN STAR as C (on C.ID = A.ID
    AND C.Data = ’DEMO1’
    AND C.POS= ’POS1’)
LEFT OUTER JOIN STAR as D (on D.ID = A.ID
    AND D.Data = ’DEMO2’
    AND D.POS= ‘POS2’)
LEFT OUTER JOIN STAR as E on E.ID = A.ID
    AND E.Data = ’DEMO3’
    AND E.POS= ‘POS3’
```

Comment: try changing from (((A to from (A.  Also, have you looked at the query builder UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got my way through parenthesis.

```
 Select ….
    Into ….
    From (((A
    Inner join B on A.ID=B.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STAR as C on (C.ID = A.ID
        AND C.Data = ’DEMO1’
        AND C.POS= ’POS1’))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STAR as D on (D.ID = A.ID
        AND D.Data = ’DEMO2’
        AND D.POS= ‘POS2’))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STAR as E on (E.ID = A.ID
        AND E.Data = ’DEMO3’
        AND E.POS= ‘POS3’)
```

Answer (score 0):

consider

```
Select ….
Into ….
From 
(A Inner join B on A.ID=B.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
STAR as C on 
C.ID = A.ID AND 
((C.Data =  ’DEMO1’ AND C.POS= ’POS1’) OR
(C.Data =  ’DEMO2’ AND C.POS= ’POS2’) or
(C.Data =  ’DEMO3’ AND C.POS= ’POS3’))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I corrected the placements of parenthesis, i have posted my answer.